# Fill up value by comparing with a field

Tags: ms-access

I have this 2 column, name it A and B
I need to fill in column B with the Pay Element ID. Meaning Employee 1-3 needs to be filled with 0001 and Employee 4-6 with 0002.

My algorithm is if the current value is blank, insert it with the previous row's value. But it doesn't work as the execution is not sequential down the rows, instead it acts independently

Pay Element ID | 0001

Employee 1 |

Employee 2 |

Employee 3 |

Pay Element ID | 0002

Employee 4 |

Employee 5 |

Employee 6 |

EDIT: I don't actually have to compare any values. I just need to pad column B with the last found, non null value.

Comment: If these 8 rows are all records in the same table, then your table structure is wrong. If field A is "employee_name", then why are there two records with "Pay Element ID" in this field? If you sorted by this field then these two rows would go to the bottom, and the table would be completely meaningless.

If I have misunderstood the structure, please comment.

Comment: @MarkButler You are correct that the structure is totally meaningless and doesn't make sense. It is from an excel file that is generated which have no structure of the sort. I only need to fill it in with some data and extract it from query. So my question is, to fill Employee 1-3 with 0001 and Employee 4-6 with 0002. I am not sure what build in functions MS Access have to deal with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My table is set up like this:

[image: table structure]

I made employee_id a Short Text field; if it is a numeric field then some of the code will have to change slightly.

Note that you will need some sort of ID field to sort the table in the order you want.

Make a copy of your table in case something goes wrong, then put this in a new module and run it:

```
Private Sub FillDown()

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strLastID As String

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblEmployees ORDER BY ID"
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)

    strLastID = ""

    rs.MoveFirst

    Do While Not rs.EOF
        If Not Nz(rs![employee_id]) = "" Then
            strLastID = rs![employee_id]
        Else
            rs.Edit
            rs![employee_id] = strLastID
            rs.Update
        End If

        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```